# Where do I configure this AutoMapper in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I'm using the normal ASP.NET not the .NET Core.

At the moment, the mapping is working well BUT I put the following Initialize code in the **controller** and called within the controller which after researching this is probably not a good idea.

So attempted to make it creating a new class to initialize and then called from Global.asax. But I'm having an issue - ***'Mapper' does not contain a definition for 'Initialize'***. It looks like I'm using an old version of AutoMapper or something. I read this on the doco: Configuration should only happen once per AppDomain. That means the best place to put the configuration code is in application startup, such as the Global.asax file for ASP.NET applications. Typically, the configuration bootstrapper class is in its own class, and this bootstrapper class is called from the startup method. The bootstrapper class should construct a MapperConfiguration object to configure the type maps.

So how this fits into the current attempts that I have?

My next question, once this setup properly, how do I call this within the Controller then?

I'm appreciated your feedback/comment.

Thanks

**Current config within a controller (probably not a good idea - BUT working):**

```
private MapperConfiguration configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
     cfg.CreateMap<Activity, ActivityDTO>()
        .ForMember(dst => dst.OwnerId, src => src.MapFrom(ol => ol.User.Id))
        .ForMember(dst => dst.OwnerName, src => src.MapFrom(ol => ol.User.FirstName + " " + ol.User.LastName))
        .ForMember(dst => dst.CategoryName, src => src.MapFrom(ol => ol.Category.Name));
    cfg.CreateMap<ActivityDTO, Activity>()
       .ForMember(dst => dst.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()));
});
```

**Current method calling the configuration above:**

```
var activitiesDTO = await (db.Activities
    .Include(b => b.User)
    .Include(c => c.Category)
    .Where(q => q.UserId == userId)
    .ProjectTo< ActivityDTO>(configuration)
    .AsQueryable()
    .ApplySort(sortfields)
    .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)).ToListAsync();
```

---

**Attempted - failed:**

**AutomapperWebProfile.cs:**

```
public class AutomapperWebProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
    {
        public AutomapperWebProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Activity, ActivityDTO>()
                .ForMember(dst => dst.OwnerId, src => src.MapFrom(ol => ol.User.Id))
                .ForMember(dst => dst.OwnerName, src => src.MapFrom(ol => ol.User.FirstName + " " + ol.User.LastName))
                .ForMember(dst => dst.CategoryName, src => src.MapFrom(ol => ol.Category.Name));

            CreateMap<ActivityDTO, Activity>()
                .ForMember(dst => dst.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()));
        }

        public static void Run()
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(a =>
            {
               a.AddProfile<AutomapperWebProfile>();
            });
        }
    }
```

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AutomapperWebProfile.Run();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
        .JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
        .Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);         
}
```

Comment: Typically, you'd have a DI container that you'd configure for startup. Then you would obtain the configuration or mapper instance through the controller's constructor parameter. Without the DI container, you can instantiate the mapper in your controller constructor -- yes, each controller where you need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching further, I came up with this approach which similar to what I did previously but it's more available to any:

**AutomapperConfig.cs:**

```
public class ClientMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public ClientMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Activity, ActivityDTO>()
                .ForMember(dst => dst.OwnerId, src => src.MapFrom(ol => ol.User.Id))
                .ForMember(dst => dst.OwnerName, src => src.MapFrom(ol => ol.User.FirstName + " " + ol.User.LastName))
                .ForMember(dst => dst.CategoryName, src => src.MapFrom(ol => ol.Category.Name));

            CreateMap<ActivityDTO, Activity>()
                .ForMember(dst => dst.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()));
        }
    }

    public class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public MapperConfiguration Configure()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<ClientMappingProfile>();
            });
            return config;
        }
    }
```

**XXXController.cs:**

```
public class ActivitiesController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        ....

[HttpGet]
        [Route("api/v1/Activities/{sortfields=Id}/{pagenumber=1}/{pagesize=10}", Name="GetActivities")]
        [CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 60, ServerTimeSpan = 60)]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetActivities(string sortfields, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            var config = new AutoMapperConfig().Configure();

            ...

            var activitiesDTO = await (db.Activities
                                        .Include(b => b.User)
                                        .Include(c => c.Category)
                                        .Where(q => q.UserId == userId)
                                        .ProjectTo< ActivityDTO>(config)
                                        .AsQueryable()
                                        .ApplySort(sortfields)
                                        .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)).ToListAsync();   

 ....

return Ok(Data)

}

}
```

I could potentially move `var config = new AutoMapperConfig().Configure();` into privatee properties that exposed to any methods.

Is anyone using this approach? I saw some people do the configuration via Global.asax stuff like failed attempt that I made (original question). Again not sure if this approach is an old solution either.

Your thought?